# How to implement a global semaphore class

Tags: c#, semaphore

I am trying to control access to the windows clipboard by using a semaphore. I need this semaphore to be global throughout the application because several thread access the semaphore to save data to the windows clipboard. The problem I am facing is the semaphore never decrements the counter. It is always 1 no matter how many threads access the semaphore.

```
namespace Global.GlobalLocks
{
    static public class Clipboard
    {
        static public readonly SemaphoreSlim ClipboardSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
    }
}
```

Here is how I use the above code:

```
namespace Automator.Global
{
    static public class ClipBoard
    {
        static private string _data = string.Empty;

        static public void SetData(string data)
        {
            GlobalLocks.Clipboard.ClipboardSemaphore.Wait();
            _data = data;
            Thread t = new Thread(Set);
            t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            t.Start();
            GlobalLocks.Clipboard.ClipboardSemaphore.Release(); 
        }

        static private void Set()
        {
            Clipboard.Clear();
            Clipboard.SetDataObject(_data, true);
        }

        static public string GetData()
        {
            return _data;
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: "the semaphore never decrements the counter" Reading the counter inside the semaphore is not good way to see if it works. Please try explaining your problem properly.

Comment: Instead of using the `_data` field, I think a better way would be to use lambda. E.g. `new Thread(() => Set(data))`.

Comment: The semaphore doesn't protect anything, it is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You immediately release the semaphore after starting the thread `Set`. While it is executed semaphore may be 1 or 0. Move the realease code to `Set`

```
static public void SetData(string data)
{
    GlobalLocks.Clipboard.ClipboardSemaphore.Wait();
    _data = data;
    Thread t = new Thread(Set);
    t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}

static private void Set()
{
     Clipboard.Clear();
     Clipboard.SetDataObject(_data, true);
     GlobalLocks.Clipboard.ClipboardSemaphore.Release(); 
}
```